# How to add a column value from a .csv to another one when the other columns are the same?

Tags: python, csv

I have two .csv files: File1=28 columns and 1000 rows and File2=29 columns and 100 rows. There is no index for the row, hence, I do not know which rows are the same in both files.

For each row in File 1, I want to add a new column with the value of 29. column in File2 when the other 28 columns are the same.

```
File1:
a,b,c,...,EMPTY
x,y,z,...,EMPTY

File2:
a,b,c,...,B1
x,y,z,...,B2

Output:
a,b,c,...,B1
x,y,z,...,B2
```

So far I am at the beginning;

```
with open(('File1.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=';') as test1:
    reader = csv.reader(test1)
    next(reader, None)  # ignore header
    test1 = set(row[0:28] for row in reader)
with open(('File2.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=';') as test2:
    reader = csv.reader(test2)
    next(reader, None)  # ignore header
    test2 = set(row[0:28] for row in reader)
```

Comment: Welcome to  SO Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for help with formatting your next question or answers.

Comment: Will the *matching* rows always be at the same line number in the files?  Are there lines in ```File2``` with missing information?

Comment: No they are not at the same line, File1 has 40000 rows and File2 has 2000 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `numpy.loadtxt` to load both csv files as it is more efficient and it gives a structure to the content. Then, you will have an array `f1` of 1000 X 28 values for File1 and an array `f2` of 100 X 29 for File2.

The second step would be to add a new column to File1 by using `f1 = numpy.column_stack([f1, numpy.zeros(f1.shape[0])])`.

Then, you can iterate over the smallest array with:

```
for row in f2:
    # find the row(s) in f1 with the same 28 first columns
    equal_rows = np.argwhere((f1[:, :28] == row[:28]).all(axis=1))
    for row2 in equal_rows:
        # add the last column of f2
        f1[row2[0], -1] = row[-1]
```

I hope this helps.